# Can't find reference to System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, stopwatch

I am attempting to build a simple stopwatch WPF application.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    public stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    private void startTimer()
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new ThreadStart(ShowElapsedTime));
    }
    void ShowElapsedTime()
    {
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        lblTime.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}.{2:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    }
}
}
```

and here

[image]

I am using System.Diagnostics but for some reason I cannot access the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and also I can't find System.Diagnostics in this Dialogue:

[image]

Why can't I use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and why does System.Diagnostics not appear in the references dialog?

Comment: Code is text. It's a lot easier to see when you copy and paste it *as text* than when it's in a picture (which is coming up tiny on my current screen).

Comment: `System.Diagnostics` is within the `System.dll`. I'd create a new blank Console application -> verify you can access it there. Also, when you say you cannot use it...what's error? We cannot see any error.

Comment: You've made a mistake declaring your `stopWatch` field; you forgot the declaration type. :) EDIT: The C# syntax/intellisense checker has gone nuts because of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then you cant see the red squiggly lines

Comment: @jth41: You could easily have *described* where the error was... ideally with an even shorter program. As it was, my original answer was incorrect because I couldn't read your `using` directives.

Comment: I just realize that I tried mixing VB with C#.

Comment: You have way too many mistakes in that code.  Don't just keep banging in code until you get completely lost in the error list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
```

You just have (`public stopWatch = new StopWatch`) which is not how `C#` objects are created.

`stopWatch` is the instance, `StopWatch` is the class definition.

Comment: Hmm, so if I type Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch in my code editor, this will lead to System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch appearance in the reference window?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and turns out I'd typed "StopWatch" instead of "Stopwatch". I hate case sensitivity!